# If $U$ is closed, is Span($U \cup \{z\}$) also closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am trying to go through a proof of the Hahn-Banach Theorem for a separable Banach space $X$. I was hoping the following was true since it would be helpful:

If $X$ is Banach and $U$ is a closed subspace of $X$, then for any $ z \in X$ the subspace  Span($U \cup \{z\}$) is also closed in $X$.

I tried proving it but didn't really get very far. Can anyone tell me if this is true, if so any hints for proving it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its true.

**Hint:**

Suppose that $z \not\in U$.
Using Hahn-Banach, you get $\varphi \in X'$, such that $\varphi(u) = 0$ for all $u \in U$ and $\varphi(z) \ne 0$.

Then, take a convergent sequence in $\operatorname{span}(U \cup \{z\})$ and apply $\varphi$ to this sequence.

Comment: Good to know it is true. Unfortunately I was trying to use this fact to prove (a less general version of) the Hahn-Banach theorem, so I can't really use your hint for proving it without being circular.

Comment: Why do you need the closeness in this proof of Hahn-Banach?